# How can I initialize an array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, runtime-error, object-initialization

I've written this code but I have some errors when I try to initialize an array of `Critter` objects and don't know what they're about.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Critter {
private:
    string crName;
public:
    Critter(string = "Poochie");
    string getName() const { return crName; }
};

Critter::Critter(string n) {
    crName = n;
}

int main() {
    Critter c[10] = { "bob","neo","judy","patrik","popo" }; //here
    return 0;
}
```

**The errors:**

```
E0415 - no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [4]" to "Critter"
...
4 more like this.
```

This code worked on a friend's Visual Studio 2017, but not in mine which is the 2019 version.

Thanks.

Comment: https://ideone.com/he9Ppn

Comment: Plenty of fine answers already, but yet another way to initialize it would be to put `using namespace std::literals::string_literals;` in scope, then do `Critter c[10] = { "bob"s, "neo"s, "judy"s, "patrik"s, "popo"s };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `Critter c[10] = { "bob","neo","judy","patrik","popo" };`

This defines an array of `const char *`. To initialize an array of `Critter` with those strings, instead:

> `Critter c[10] = { {"bob"}, {"neo"}, {"judy"}, {"patrik"}, {"popo"} };`

---

[ *EDIT* ] It was pointed out that the same answer was first posted in a comment, only it was hidden in an external link with no indication of what's behind it, which I did not see before posting the above. Credit goes to @drescherjm so I'll leave this here as a CW.

Answer (score 10):

The initialization you have is for an array of strings, for the objects you need:

```
Critter c[10] = {Critter("bob"), Critter("neo"), Critter("judy"),
                 Critter("patrik"), Critter("popo")};
```

Or

```
Critter c[10] = {{"bob"}, {"neo"}, {"judy"}, //(*)
                 {"patrik"}, {"popo"}};
```

> *`*`This second method is credited to [@drescherjm comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394106/why-i-cant-make-an-array-of-my-class-objects/62394270#comment110350117_62394106) followed by [@dxiv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62394270/6865932), both mentioned it first.*

This second initialization may be what your friend used, and maybe you forgot the braces, the IDE version difference doesn't seem relevant here.

Note that C++ provides a container for fixed size arrays, [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<Critter, 10> c = {Critter("bob"), Critter("neo"),
                             Critter("judy"), Critter("patrik"), Critter("popo")};
```

On a side note:

[You should avoid `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6865932)

Answer (score 0):

`string c[10] = {"bob","neo","judy","patrik","popo"};` Would be correct.

`{"bob","neo","judy","patrik","popo"}` is an array containing string elements.

You need to do

```
Critter c[10]={ Critter("bob"),Critter("neo"),Critter("judy"),Critter("patrik"),Critter("popo")};
```

Answer (score -1):

C++ only allows one "user-defined conversion" at a time.

You're providing `char const[N]`s (let's call them `char const*`s for the sake of argument), which need to be turned into `std::string`s (which count as "user-defined" in this context), which need to be turned into `Critter`s.

That's two conversions, not one.

That's just a limitation of C++, I'm afraid. You'll have to temporarily instantiate either strings or `Critter`s within that initialiser.